# Why can I not consistently clear the default gateway?

Tags: powershell, networking, windows-10

I want a little script to toggle between DHCP and a static IP for some servers I run.

The below script works intermittently. When it fails it often fails with: "`New-NetIPAddress : Instance DefaultGateway already exists`"

I do not understand why this is not an easy to make reliable script.

```bsh
$WiFiAdapter = Get-NetAdapter -Name "Wi-Fi"
$IPInterfaces = $WiFiAdapter | Get-NetIPInterface

$DhcpEnabled = $null;
$WiFiIPv4 = $null;

foreach ($IPInterfaceEntries in $IPInterfaces)
{
    if ($IPInterfaceEntries.AddressFamily -eq "IPv4")
    {
        if ($IPInterfaceEntries.Dhcp -eq "Enabled")
        {
            $DhcpEnabled = $true
            $WiFiIPv4 = $IPInterfaceEntries
        }
        elseif ($IPInterfaceEntries.Dhcp -eq "Disabled" )
        {
            $DhcpEnabled = $false
            $WiFiIPv4 = $IPInterfaceEntries
        }
    }
}

if ($DhcpEnabled -eq $true)
{
    Write-Output "Disabling DHCP"
    
    $WiFiAdapter | Set-NetIPInterface -Dhcp Disabled
    $WiFiAdapter | Remove-NetIPAddress -Confirm $false
    $WiFiAdapter | Remove-NetRoute -Confirm $false
    $WiFiAdapter | New-NetIPAddress -IPAddress 192.168.0.100 -PrefixLength 24 -AddressFamily IPv4 -DefaultGateway 192.168.0.1
    Set-DnsClientServerAddress -InterfaceAlias $WiFiAdapter.InterfaceAlias -ServerAddresses 192.168.0.1
}
else
{
    Write-Output "Enabling DHCP"

    Set-DnsClientServerAddress -InterfaceAlias "Wi-Fi" -ResetServerAddresses
    $WiFiAdapter | Set-NetIPInterface -Dhcp Enabled
}
```

Comment: This is not a PowerShell issue or code issue. It is a Windows OS, resource release issue. When you do this even in the UI, it looks immediate, but it isn't, because using the UI and human takes several seconds to click X or Y and even when you do, you often have to close a reopen the UI to see the change. So, try using delays (sleep) and or release commands (i.e., IPConfig /release and renew when you do the DHCP switch) in your code

Comment: After performing some of those commands, it might be best to wait and verify changes (in a loop, with `Start-Sleep`) before proceeding to the next command.  For example, `while ('Enabled' -eq (($WiFiAdapter | Get-NetIPInterface).Dhcp)) { Start-Sleep -Seconds 2 }`, etc.  Or, you could add this logic around `New-NetIPAddress` when it throws that error.  Also, ensure your code is running as an administrator.